# unable to find address of view in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to finish the user authentication cakephp tutorial here. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

If you look in the chunk of code for the UsersController it shows an action for edit. The only view they provide is for add.ctp so I'm trying to finish out the remaining views. I made an index already, but now I can't figure out what's going on with the edit view.

When I go to users/edit I get the following message

```
Error: The requested address '/cake/users/edit' was not found on this server.
```

I have a page saved as edit.ctp in my Users folder so I'm confused as to why I'm getting this message.

Here's the edit function in UsersController by the way

```
public function edit($id = null) { 
    $this->User->id = $id; 
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {  
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) { 
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {  
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
    }
}
```

Am I just supposed to create another view and pass it off to the edit function? I'm confused why I can add users via the add function, but I can't edit my own password/username/whatever user attributes.

Comment: What happens when you provide a valid user id, e.g. `users/edit/1` ? The action throws a `NotFoundException` if you don't pass a valid id.

Comment: what is the path of this view edit.ctp ?

Comment: @DougOwings what you said works perfectly. Sorry, still a newb to cake and trying to figure things out.